# Syllable stress of the word begonias

Tags: stress, syllables, meter

I am currently studying syllable stress.

When I look at the word begonia we can split it into 3 syllables with the stress on 'go'. E.g bih-gohn-yuh.

However, the plural form of the word gives me 4 syllables: begonias with the 'go' still stressed. I feel like the nia should be stressed. What is the correct stress of the plural?

Is there a stressed syllable rule for plural words in English?

Comment: Syllable stress is often different in Britain, but we would stress the "go" in both singular and plural.

Comment: Why do you think there are four syllables in the plural? There are not. Try using it at the end of a line of rhymed poetry and you'll see that it rhymes with *Sonya’s* or *own yuhz*, not with *Mamma mias!* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there ***is*** a stressed syllable rule for pluralizing nouns in English: do nothing with the stress you didn’t already do in the singular.

The word [*begonia*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begonia) does **ɴᴏᴛ** rhyme with *Crimea*, *diarrhea*, or the female given name *Maria*. Instead *begonia* rhymes with the female given name *Sonya*, as heard in U.S. Supreme Justice **Sonia** Sotomayor.

That means it normally has three syllables with stress on the penult: /bəˈɡonjə/. So when you make *begonias* in the plural it’s simply /bəˈɡonjəz/ with the same stress because inflection never shifts a noun’s stress pattern in English. (Remember that in the International Phonetic Alphabet, the letter /j/ represents the consonant heard at the start of the English word *yes*.)

However, exactly where you choose to put the syllable break between the stressed syllable and the last one is a matter more of convention than of science.

If you believe in unchecked open syllables, it would be pronounced /bəˈɡo.njəz/ — and I bet the justice herself would say [bəˈɡo.ɲəz] there.
The middle syllable is pronounced like the word *go* and everything else is in that last syllable — which is therefore just "nyuh" if you're into that silly sort of spelling pronunciation. Think of it sounding a bit like this might be said:

> Maaan, sheez **so** ginna **owe**-nya, dood!

Even if you mean hyphenation for line breaks and not actual speech, it would still be written with hyphens as *be-go-nias* because those are only two places where you are supposed to break up that word to continue it on the next line in typeset text.

Comment: I, and in my experience most other British people, definitely _do_ pronounce "begonia" so that it rhymes with Maria. However we also emphasise the second syllable in both singular and plural forms. Whether pronouncing it "be GO nee ah" counts as four syllables, though, I'm not so sure.

Comment: @BoldBen To rhyme with Maria, /mə ˈɹiː . ə/ "muh-REE-uh", you're claiming you say /bɨ . ɡə ˈniː . ə/ so with fake spelling, "big-guh-NEE-uh". **I find this ɪɴᴄʀᴇᴅɪʙʟʏ difficult to imagine❗** Could you please point me at a clip where I can listen to this cray-cray-crazy thing⁇ [This young English woman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwXB8dszE0o) is not doing it: she’s saying what I’ve said it's said like. Even [this older English genteman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN17CwlOBrg) is saying it exactly as I indicated. Did you not understand the IPA transcription? Clips or didn't happen.

Comment: @BoldBen *Begonia* rhymes with *Justice **SO**-nya*, while *Maria* rhymes with *She’d never **SEE**-ya*.  Those do not share the same rime at all! "REE-yuh" and "SOH-nyuh" do not have same stressed vowel (/i/ vs /o/) through the end of each word and so you cannot rhyme them even with feminine rhyme. What am I missing here? I cheerfully accept demonstrations in perfectly rhymed and metered verse — should you would care to respond with such. :)

Comment: I hope when this is settled we can let begonias be begonias.

Comment: If Sonia Sotomayor. pronounces her first name to rhyme with "begonia", we need a better example. Every Sonia I've ever heard of is pronounced with a short o as in "on". For rhymes I suggest ammonia and Estonia (IME people pronounce "begonia" with 4 syllables).

Comment: @tchrist I admit that I'm not really familiar with IPA but I was comparing the pronunciation by Peter Seabrook and the young woman with what I perceive to be the pronunciation of 'Sonia' and 'Maria'. The gardening experts definitely pronounce "begonia" as I do but, to me, that sounds like the way that I would pronounce "Maria" in and _not_ like the way I would pronounce "Sonia".

Comment: The fan palm Washingtonia . . . has more syllables than a begonia.

Comment: Alright so making a word plural does not change the syllable stress. However, in the case of begonias, does it add another syllable? 3 or 4 syllables?

Comment: @user1261710 No. *Begonias* has [3 syllables](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/begonia). The last syllable is "NYAZ" not "AZ". "NI" is not its own syllable here. [Listen to Peter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN17CwlOBrg).  It rhymes with *loan ya* in the singular and *loan yas* in the plural. There are no LOW-KNEE-ASS anywhere. I'm sorry to talk baby-talk but people don't understand IPA.

Comment: Onward, anglophones - to Tunisia. Brits and Yanks face off.